# Extract Data from Dynamic Link When App is already opened- Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I have generated the QR codes from the dynamic links so that when the user scans the QR code from a third-party scanner it opens my app and opens a particular page based on the data extracted from the dynamic link.
But the problem is when the user scans the QR code from my app's inbuilt QR code scanner it's giving me the dynamic link and not the data present in the dynamic link.

Is there a way to extract the data from the firebase dynamic link if the app is already opened?

Comment: Please try https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

Comment: thanks for your comment @SheetalGhori since the firebase dynamic link has been already integrated with the app, is there a way to do the same with the firebase dynamic link?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem by adding data after the dynamic link followed by "?" example `https://example.link/shad?myDataKey=value`.
The key pair value added after "?" is neglected in the dynamic link.